# How can hit points lost as a result of casting the Life Transference spell be recovered?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, hit-points

When you "sacrifice" hit points as a result of casting the *life transference* spell, how can you recover them? A long or short rest?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 18):

#### Damage from *life transference* can be healed by any means

The spell description for [*life transference*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/life-transference) (XGtE, p. 160) states:

> You sacrifice some of your health to mend another creature's injuries. You take 4d8 necrotic damage, which can't be reduced in any way, and one creature of your choice that you can see within range regains a number of hit points equal to twice the necrotic damage you take. [...]

The first sentence of the description "You sacrifice some of your health to mend another creature's injuries." is descriptive, and does not contain any actual mechanical effects of the spell. The actual mechanical effects of using the spell are that you take 4d8 necrotic damage.

Notably, the spell never states that there is anything special about this damage (besides the fact that it cannot be reduced in any way); thus, for all intents and purposes, it is just like any other damage. Thus, it can be healed by anything that would ordinarily restore hit points, be that magic, short rests, long rests, or anything else.

Comment: Sorry for the question aside but which class is that spell for? I am curious and dont have access to Xanathars guide for now. Thank you

Comment: @MivaScott: Lol, it was indeed.

Comment: I wonder what the purpose is of typing this damage as necrotic if the damage cannot be reduced.

Comment: @MichaelW. Short answer: it can be increased still!

Comment: @bibleblade *Life transference* is on the cleric and wizard spell lists.

Comment: Note that if you are vulnerable to necrotic, twice as much life is transferred.  Bwahahaha.